# HTML and css menu

Tags: html, css, border, margin, desktop

CSS and HTML file for the menu.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    src: url('Raleway-Light.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
}

/*Menu*/

ul#menu {

    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

label.show-menu {
    display: none;
}

#show-menu {
    display: none;
}


a:visited {
    border: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}


ul#menu > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul#menu  > ul.hidden {

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
ul#menu  > li li.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    float: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px;
}

ul#menu > li li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul#menu > li:first-child:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul#menu  > li:hover li.submenu {

    visibility: visible;
}

ul#menu  > li > ul.hidden > li.submenu {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul#menu  > li > ul.hidden > li.submenu > a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
}

#navinformatie {
    margin-left: 265px;
}

#navverblijf {
    margin-left: 525px;
}

#navbezienswaardigheden {
    margin-left: 650px;
}

#Logo {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 79px;
}
```

```html
<header>
     <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

        <div id="Logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
            <ul id="menu" class="mobile-top">
                <li class="hoofd"><a href="#">home</a>
                <li class="cheat"><a href="#">informatie</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">algemene info</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">wijken</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">goed om te weten</a></li>
                    </ul>

                <li class="cheat"><a href="#">verblijf</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">hotels</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">hostels</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li class="cheat"><a href="#">bezienswaardigheden</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">toers</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">entertainment</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">musicals</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">sport</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I'm trying to achieve: http://student.howest.be/marnik.bruyndonckx/eindopdrachtweb/Home.html

As you can see, I need help with the border of the first list tag that displays under the subelements of the menu.

Kevin suggested to use li:first-child to target the first items and underline it, but it seems after doing so, there's now no border at all.

Also, the margin between the menu items isn't right, it's not displaying as it should, what am I doing wrong?

I'm looking to only modify the css file, not the html menu.
I guess that the two problems I currently have only result in 1-2 mistakes I made in my css?

Comment: This code is a total mess.  You are over-qualifying all your elements, and duplicating code all over.  Your first step should be to clean all this up.  Also, if you can share a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Sean, I'm trying to achieve this: http://student.howest.be/marnik.bruyndonckx/eindopdrachtweb/Home.html

Answer (score 0):

To target the first item in the list use `first-child`:

```
li:first-child { /* override styles here */ }
```

The spacing between items is b/c you are using `display: inline-block`. This article should help: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Hello Kevin, thanks for your answer, I've updated my post (cleaned up the css file and used li:first-child) but it doesn't work, now there's no border showing at all for the first items.

I've also been looking at the article you've sent me, I've been trying both negative margin and skipping the closing tag, but both don't work. 
I need css code, I'm not able to change the HTML due to the fact another mobile css file is linked to it.